# What is your favorite word processor for the iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation

I'm hearing some information about Elements and Pages, but I wanted to ask what you're using as a word processing app on your iPad.

I'm currently using the Notes app, but I'd like to be able to work on a document (mostly just text documents) and be able to save my progress, and then optionally pick up where I left off the next time I'm in front of my office Mac.

Dropbox doesn't seem to let me edit from the iPad, and Google Docs, to my surprise, will let me view word processing documents, but not edit nor create them. (!)

Comment: When asking users to contribute to a list of answers, the question should be marked [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). I have converted this question.

Comment: @Robert: Questions cannot be marked community wiki, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I use:

- Evernote: This is good if you want to edit a text document and sycn between computers.
- Pages: So far, the best document creation tool I've used on the iPad.
- Penultimate: Great for sketching ideas and mind-mapping.

For your situation, I would suggestion Evernote.

Good luck!

Comment: Evernote and Pages generally work well for me as well. Haven't tried Penultimate yet but have been looking for a mind-mapping solution for the iPad so will be taking a look shortly.

Comment: @Rex Check out [MindNode](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fmindnode%2Fid312220102%3Fmt%3D8&rct=j&q=mindnode&ei=GSrsTreYNtHbiALZtNXNBA&usg=AFQjCNFFZ3bUKAZPCRIja392XgS6pY8bCw&sig2=TOMoWScJwK6-N4sL6sXxKA) for mind mapping. (There's also a Mac version.)

Answer (score 3):

### [Pages](http://www.apple.com/ipad/features/pages.html)

Its pretty good for a mobile app and can sync with the desktop and web app versions thru iCloud.

[Download Pages](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pages/id361309726?mt=8)

Answer (score 2):

Plaintext is nice, as is its big brother WriteRoom.

But [iA Writer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ia-writer/id392502056?mt=8) also edits files from Dropbox (or iCloud!), and it has one big advantage over those two: smart quotation marks and smart parentheses!

That's right, instead of having to use different keys for open-paren or close-paren, you just tap one key and the app automagically makes it work.

Very Apple-like!

I also use Pages when I need fancy stuff like image support. And Storyist when I want to start with an index card outline of my document. But mostly I use iA Writer.

Answer (score 0):

PlainText is a newer Universal (iPad & iPhone) text editor that is free with ads or $4.99 to remove them.  Best feature of the app is that it syncs with your Dropbox and saves your docs as plain txt files.

Answer (score 0):

I have Pages and use it for heavier lifting but for everyday writing I use Simplenote on iPhone and iPad and Notational Velocity on my Mac. It's reliable, fast, clean, and simple.

http://simplenoteapp.com/

http://notational.net/